# How to get stock of finance yahoo API

Tags: yahoo-finance

I want to get data of some selected stock of finance yahoo API. I am listing these API here .

```
Chart 
http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AAPL+Interactive#
Key statistics
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAPL+Key+Statistics
Competitors
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/co?s=AAPL+Competitors
Analyst Opinion
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ao?s=AAPL+Analyst+Opinion
Analyst Estimates


http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=AAPL+Analyst+Estimates
Major Holders
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=AAPL+Major+Holders
Income Statement (annual and Quarterly)
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL
Balance Sheet (annual and Quarterly)
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL+Balance+Sheet&annual
Cash Flow (annual and Quarterly)
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=AAPL+Cash+Flow&annual
```

Is there any api which give me exact solution for this.Even it is paid.Please Provide me correct and sufficient information also thanks in advance.

Comment: This is offtopic here; you need to go search for paid and free stock information APIs, also scraping. Noone can possibly know what you mean by *"which gives me exact solution"*, unless you state a specific question e.g. "find APPL's Forward P/E for the last n quarters". Also check out http://money.stackexchange.com

Comment: Like https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=API . This is Analyst Estimates type stock data .In samw way I need above selected option with their respective data.As there are no of option avail : summary, Order extra. But here I required on these above option as I mentioned.After click on option I will get respective page data

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of what you're looking for using the yahoo_fin package in Python.  Its documentation is here: http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/.

Here's some examples:

Pulling analyst info (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysts?p=AAPL):

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *

get_analysts_info("AAPL")
```

Income statment:

```
get_income_statement("AAPL")
```

Cash flow statment:

```
get_cash_flow("AAPL")
```

Balance sheet:

```
get_balance_sheet("AAPL")
```

Key statistics (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL):

```
get_stats("AAPL")
```

Major holders (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/holders?p=AAPL):

```
get_holders("AAPL")
```

You just need to replace "AAPL" with whatever ticker you want data for.